# Login Administrador Usuario Panel de Control

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, formularios, login

La situación es la siguiente:

He estado haciendo pruebas con un login que acabo de construir. Sin embargo, cada que inicio sesión con cualquiera de los tipos de usuario no me direcciona a su respectivo panel de control.

Cada vez que inicio sesión me manda a la página del Dashboard de Xampp. Prácticamente me redirige afuera de la carpeta del proyecto. Y si saco de la carpeta el archivo Panel_Administrador.php solamente así me funciona el login.

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa?

Les comparto el código:
**ACTUALIZACION**

index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["login"])){

if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

$query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    $dbusertype=$row['usertype'];
    }
    if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword){

    $_SESSION['session_usertype']=$dbusertype;

    switch ($dbusertype){
    case 1:
        $Usertype = "Panel_Administrador.php";
        $numero = 1;
    break;
    case 2:
        $Usertype = "Panel_Usuario.php";
        $numero = 2;
    break;
    case 3:
        $Usertype = "Panel_Externo.php";
        $numero = 3;
    break;
}
    echo "<script>window.location.href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plataforma/".$Usertype."';</script>";
    exit;
    }
} else {
    $message =  "Nombre de usuario ó contraseña invalida!";
}
} else {
    $message = "Todos los campos son requeridos!";
}
}
?>
```

valida_usuario.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$vista = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$vista = explode("/",$vista);
    
if(isset($_SESSION["session_usertype"])){

switch($_SESSION["session_usertype"]){
case 1:
    $Usertype = "Panel_Administrador.php";
    $numero = 1;
break;
case 2:
    $Usertype = "Panel_Usuario.php";
    $numero = 2;
break;
case 3:
    $Usertype = "Panel_Externo.php";
    $numero = 3;
break;
}
 if($Usertype != $vista[1]){
    session_destroy();
    echo "<script>window.location.href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plataforma/".$Usertype."';</script>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<script>window.location.href='http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/plataforma/".$Usertype."';</script>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La redirección al dashboard de Xampp, se debe al valor que esta devolviendo la variable **$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']**. Como estas trabajando en local, es muy probable que devuelva el valor definido en la configuración Apache (localhost o 127.0.0.1).

Por lo tanto al momento de imprimir esta linea

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$Usertype."';</script>";
```

se esta mostrando esto (para el caso de administrador):

```
<script>window.location.href='https://localhost/Panel_Administrador.php';</script>
```

lo cual esta incorrecto dado que estas trabajando tu proyecto en otra carpeta, por ende la linea de código debiese ser así:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/Carpeta_del_proyecto/".$Usertype."';</script>";
```

Si tu proyecto lo tienes con un *virtual host*, es recomendable que utilices url relativas   y no absolutas dado que al momento de implementar tu proyecto podrías tener problemas con la estructura de la ruta. Quedaria asi.

```
echo "<script>window.location.href='/".$Usertype."';</script>";
```

el caracter "/" en la url, el *browser* (navegador) lo reconoce como tu *hostname*.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda, cualquier percance no dudes en consultar. :)

Comment: Tu explicación estuvo genial.
He realizado los ajustes correspondientes pero ahora me dice
_Notice: Undefined variable: Usertype in C:\xampp\htdocs\plataforma\includes\valida_usuario.php on line 27_ .
Por consiguiente, no inicia sesión ni nada.

Comment: Una duda, ¿Que finalidad tiene el archivo **valida_usuario.php**?. Por lo que entiendo en index.php, recibes los datos de un formulario e inicias sesión.

Comment: *valida_usuario.php* verifica que los datos sean correctos y los dirija a su respectivo panel. De lo contrario, los regresa al *index.php* para iniciar sesión nuevamente.
También restringe la navegación de un usuario nivel 2 en las páginas del usuario nivel 1.